# double border around a container

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I wanted to create an effect like this around my border, basically a double sided border. Currently I am using an image as a background-image, but the issue comes when I want to make the site responsive. So I want to re-create this using CSS. Is this even possible?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes use `border-style:double;` and for inverted round border you can use jquery-plugin ([jquery.corner.js](https://github.com/malsup/corner)) `$(this).corner("bite");` also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4012085/2683447).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible to have a double border.

Example -

```
#myDiv {
    border:1px double black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will put the double border.

CSS

```
p{
    border-style:double;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>A double border.</p>
```