# How do I create this inverted two layer border?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is there any way to make custom scoop border style in CSS or jQuery?

Like the image below:

[image]

Comment: What did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012085/is-there-any-way-to-invert-a-rounded-corner-in-css

Comment: Please don't ask the exact same question twice.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using a single `div` with `:after` and `:before` :pseudo-elements and `radial-gradient`s.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left, #ECECEC 3%, transparent 3%), -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom left, #ECECEC 3%, transparent 3%), -webkit-radial-gradient(top right, #ECECEC 3%, transparent 3%), -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom right, #ECECEC 3%, transparent 3%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(top left, #ECECEC 3%, transparent 3%), -moz-radial-gradient(bottom left, #ECECEC 3%, transparent 3%), -moz-radial-gradient(top right, #ECECEC 3%, transparent 3%), -moz-radial-gradient(bottom right, #ECECEC 3%, transparent 3%);
  background: radial-gradient(top left, #ECECEC 3%, transparent 3%), radial-gradient(bottom left, #ECECEC 3%, transparent 3%), radial-gradient(top right, #ECECEC 3%, transparent 3%), radial-gradient(bottom right, #ECECEC 3%, transparent 3%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 40px solid #ECECEC;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 30px;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 103%;
  height: 103%;
  left: -1.5%;
  top: -1.5%;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left, white 3%, transparent 3%), -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom left, white 3%, transparent 3%), -webkit-radial-gradient(top right, white 3%, transparent 3%), -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom right, white 3%, transparent 3%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(top left, white 3%, transparent 3%), -moz-radial-gradient(bottom left, white 3%, transparent 3%), -moz-radial-gradient(top right, white 3%, transparent 3%), -moz-radial-gradient(bottom right, white 3%, transparent 3%);
  background: radial-gradient(top left, white 3%, transparent 3%), radial-gradient(bottom left, white 3%, transparent 3%), radial-gradient(top right, white 3%, transparent 3%), radial-gradient(bottom right, white 3%, transparent 3%);
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 0;
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 106%;
  height: 106%;
  left: -3%;
  top: -3%;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left, #ECECEC 4%, transparent 4%), -webkit-radial-gradient(bottom left, #ECECEC 4%, transparent 4%), -webkit-radial-gradient(top right, #ECECEC 4%, transparent 4%), -moz-radial-gradient(bottom right, #ECECEC 4%, transparent 4%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(top left, #ECECEC 4%, transparent 4%), -moz-radial-gradient(bottom left, #ECECEC 4%, transparent 4%), -moz-radial-gradient(top right, #ECECEC 4%, transparent 4%), -moz-radial-gradient(bottom right, #ECECEC 4%, transparent 4%);
  background: radial-gradient(top left, #ECECEC 4%, transparent 4%), radial-gradient(bottom left, #ECECEC 4%, transparent 4%), radial-gradient(top right, #ECECEC 4%, transparent 4%), radial-gradient(bottom right, #ECECEC 4%, transparent 4%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  <br />
  <br />Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
  sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt
  ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit
  esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is not working as responsive - when changing width.

Comment: @AtiarRahman - The `radial-gradient`s' depend on the `width` and `height` of the `div`. You can't have same border size for all `width`s. [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/KwNzoJ)