# Create inverted curved corners in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have several div tags on my website which have a solid border(a square) around the div. Something like in the image below.

[image: Something like this]

I want to achieve this style as shown in the image below.

[image]

My limitation is that I need to get this done through CSS or Javascript only, I cannot add any extra HTML code.

I have tried some CSS code and Js code but I was not able to achieve this style.

CSS code :

```css
.testimonial {
background-size: 4% 5%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, rgba(0,0,0,0) 20px, #000 21px);
border-style:solid;
height:300px;
width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonial"></div>
```

I used jQuery corner js but it was also did not work. The output was the image below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$(".testimonial").corner("bite keep 15px cc:#000");
});
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012085/invert-rounded-corner-in-css

Comment: Here is a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/4w01xqyj/

Comment: and online generator for this: https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, but it is not working for me on my container(div) on which I want to add an inverted border. It already has a square border.