SVG Path: Have a non-scaling cruve with scaling lines
As usual, the question indicated as a duplicate has outdated or incoherent answers
This question is about SVGs
I'm not interested by "hacks" with box shadows or pseudo elements, they multiply tech debt and always end up posing other problems

I'm trying to create a shape to be used with clip-path on buttons and dialogs
The shape is fairly simple:

However, when applied to rectangular buttons, the edges get scaled down (as they should). Making it look wrong :

Ideally, I would want this path to scale like this :

Is it possible to give a fixed position to path curves but not its lines ?


.svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clipped {
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  clip-path: url(#my-clip-path);
}
<svg class="svg">
  <clipPath id="my-clip-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"><path d="M0,0.1 v0.8 c0.05,0,0.1,0.05,0.1,0.1 h0.8 c0,-0.05,0.05,-0.1,0.1,-0.1 v-0.8 C0.95,0.1,0.9,0.05,0.9,0 h-0.8 C0.1,0.06,0.05,0.1,0,0.1"></path></clipPath>
</svg>

<button class="clipped">Some rectangular button</button>




This is an article about how to do it using css: https://css-tricks.com/scooped-corners-in-2018/ Also take a look at this dabblet (Lea Verou) https://dabblet.com/gist/10168919

https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/#2

Is your question really about SVGs, or is it about the best way to achieve a particular visual effect? As regards SVG, no, you cannot scale some parts of it but not others. SVG is not the right tool to solve this problem. The link @TemaniAfif posted is great, but #1 might be all you need, and it doesn't require a pseudo-element. #2 does require a pseudo-element, but there is no logical reason to avoid pseudo-elements.

@BrettDonald and I already provided an answer in the duplicate (you voted to reopen) using those links as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73510336/8620333
